# Variable 'SQ_LIB' hides a variable in the enclosing block

Tags: asp.net, variables, stored-procedures, foreach, parameter-passing

I've searched other forums and understand in each code example why this error is returned, but can't see why it is returned in my code below since I've only declared 'intReleaseMasterID' once.  I'm trying to pass this variable declared and determined outside the loop into the loop and use the same variable for each iteration of the loop - can this be done?.  Any suggestions?

```
Protected Sub btnOrder_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnOrder.Click
    Dim SQ_LIB As New SQL_Lib
    Dim intReleaseMasterID As Integer
    Dim param(1) As SqlParameter
    param(0) = SQ_LIB.AddParameter("@UserName", Membership.GetUser().UserName)
    param(1) = SQ_LIB.AddParameter("@ReleaseMasterID", Data.ParameterDirection.Output, 0)
    SQ_LIB.RunProcedure("ReleaseMasterToPrimaryLocation", param)
    intReleaseMasterID = CInt(param(1).Value)

    For Each item As GridDataItem In RadGrid1.SelectedItems
        Response.Write(item("InventoryDetailSerialID").Text.ToString())
        Dim strInventoryDetailSerialID As String = item.GetDataKeyValue("InventoryDetailSerialID")
        Dim SQ_LIB As New SQL_Lib
        Dim param(2) As SqlParameter
        param(0) = SQ_LIB.AddParameter("@InventoryDetailSerialID", strInventoryDetailSerialID)
        param(1) = SQ_LIB.AddParameter("@UserName", Membership.GetUser().UserName)
        param(2) = SQ_LIB.AddParameter("@ReleaseMasterID", intReleaseMasterID)
        SQ_LIB.RunProcedure("ReleaseDetailsToPrimaryLocation", param)
    Next
End Sub
```

I've added another subroutine so that parameter variables aren't in the same scope, but either the CreatePartOrders subroutine never runs or can't get information from RadGrid1.SelectedItems or I'm not passing the intReleaseMasterID variable correctly.  Which is it?

```
    Protected Sub btnOrder_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnOrder.Click
    Dim SQ_LIB As New SQL_Lib
    Dim intReleaseMasterID As Integer
    Dim param(1) As SqlParameter
    param(0) = SQ_LIB.AddParameter("@UserName", Membership.GetUser().UserName)
    param(1) = SQ_LIB.AddParameter("@ReleaseMasterID", Data.ParameterDirection.Output, 0)
    SQ_LIB.RunProcedure("ReleaseMasterToPrimaryLocation", param)
    intReleaseMasterID = CInt(param(1).Value)

    CreatePartOrders(intReleaseMasterID)
End Sub
___________________________________________________________
Public Sub CreatePartOrders(ByVal intReleaseMasterID As Integer)
    For Each item As GridDataItem In RadGrid1.SelectedItems
        Response.Write(item("InventoryDetailSerialID").Text.ToString())
        Dim strInventoryDetailSerialID As String = item.GetDataKeyValue("InventoryDetailSerialID")
        Dim SQ_LIB As New SQL_Lib
        Dim param(2) As SqlParameter
        param(0) = SQ_LIB.AddParameter("@InventoryDetailSerialID", strInventoryDetailSerialID)
        param(1) = SQ_LIB.AddParameter("@UserName", Membership.GetUser().UserName)
        param(2) = SQ_LIB.AddParameter("@ReleaseMasterID", intReleaseMasterID)
        SQ_LIB.RunProcedure("ReleaseDetailsToPrimaryLocation", param)
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: @Miki -- error is same as post title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating SQL_Lib in two places, marked below...

```
Protected Sub btnOrder_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnOrder.Click
    Dim SQ_LIB As New SQL_Lib **HERE is number 1**
    Dim intReleaseMasterID As Integer
    Dim param(1) As SqlParameter
    param(0) = SQ_LIB.AddParameter("@UserName", Membership.GetUser().UserName)
    param(1) = SQ_LIB.AddParameter("@ReleaseMasterID", Data.ParameterDirection.Output, 0)
    SQ_LIB.RunProcedure("ReleaseMasterToPrimaryLocation", param)
    intReleaseMasterID = CInt(param(1).Value)

    For Each item As GridDataItem In RadGrid1.SelectedItems
        Response.Write(item("InventoryDetailSerialID").Text.ToString())
        Dim strInventoryDetailSerialID As String = item.GetDataKeyValue("InventoryDetailSerialID")
        Dim SQ_LIB As New SQL_Lib **HERE is number 2**
        Dim param(2) As SqlParameter
        param(0) = SQ_LIB.AddParameter("@InventoryDetailSerialID", strInventoryDetailSerialID)
        param(1) = SQ_LIB.AddParameter("@UserName", Membership.GetUser().UserName)
        param(2) = SQ_LIB.AddParameter("@ReleaseMasterID", intReleaseMasterID)
        SQ_LIB.RunProcedure("ReleaseDetailsToPrimaryLocation", param)
    Next
End Sub
```

You are using Dim and As to declare it twice.

Comment: (thanks for your quick response!) I changed the 2nd instance of 'Dim SQL_LIB' to 'Dim SQL_LIB2' (and corresponding parameters) and now get "Variable 'param' hides a variable in an enclosing block".  I think the real issue is with the "intReleaseMasterID" variable.  Any ideas?

Comment: uh, no... Dim param(1) and Dim param(2) are considered the same name of the variable, despite having a different array size, you are declaring that twice as well.

Comment: see edits and questions above.  (I apologize for the continued questions, and I'm sure my inexperience is showing!)

Comment: you had directed me to the correct solution and the added subroutine shown in the edit above resolved the issue, but only after a few more hours struggling only to find that my stored procedure was expecting one more parameter.  Thanks for your help!